# VS Code как сделать запрет переноса строк html в jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, create-react-app

1. При сохранении компонента на react в jsx html разметка переносится неправильно на новые строки, с ошибками как это исправить?
2. В редакторе стоит плагин prettier, (я его правил но безуспешно)
3. Включена в настройках "editor.formatOnSave": true

[image: Как избежать неправильые переносы при сохранении?]

Comment: Аналогичная проблема. Не могу найти данный плагин, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: вариант 1) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets .  Вариан 2) js ваилы переименовывать окончания в формат .jsx и тогда все будет ок и без плагина

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вопрос закрыт,

1. Элемент списка все решилось установкой плагина - JavaScript VS Code JavaScript (ES6) snippets, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets
2. Либо изменить расширения фаила .js на .jsx и тогда все будет гуд
3. в настройках vs code пропишите: "files.associations": {
   "*.js": "javascriptreact"
   }

Comment: Так и удалите вопрос, для других он не представляет никакой ценности.

Comment: Это вы решили за всех ? я думал тут надо показывать решения для помощи другим разработчикам, которые сталкиваются со схожими задачами, или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: Это я не решил за всех, а предложил. Мне лично кажется, что ценность что вопроса, что ответа, примерно в районе нуля, но если вы считаете иначе, то не удаляйте, конечно.

Comment: Как интересно... а почему именно этот плагин установили ? откуда узнали ? :) тож столкнулся с этой проблемой) установил плагин и норм. Спаисбо!

Comment: Долго искал, нашел на англоязычном рессурсе)

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку с Sublime Babel!

Comment: Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой и выше упомянутый плагин Sublime Babel тоже помог. Спасибо автору.